# Can we have more than one file type field in SugarCrm module?

Tags: file, types, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5 CE. I want to use 2 file type fields in one custom module so that I can upload 2 documents and download them from detailview whenever needed. It working fine for one single File type field in one module.

So I want to know whether we can have multiple File Type field in one custom module or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can by default. I do have a custom file upload type field that allows for multiple custom file type fields available for purchase: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/file-upload-module

Comment: I am not asking about the custom file upload type field....instead I am asking about the default 'File' type SugarField which is also used in default Notes module.

Comment: Read my first sentence. I don't believe you can by default. You would have to change the way SugarCRM handles files to do so. This is what the custom file upload file type already does.